# How to draw sprites using batch.draw() from pyglet library in Python

Tags: python, graphics, pyglet

This might seem like a duplicate and maybe it is but I'm using windows 10 and sprite.py only has v2i in one place and changing it doesn't fix the issue.
Maybe I'm using batch drawing wrong so I've provided the code. draw() is called from game object by on_draw() function.

```py
class Island:
    def __init__(self):
        self.island = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],]
        self.tile_width = 30
        self.offsetx = 350
        self.offsety = 100
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.water_tile = pyglet.image.load("path")
        self.grass_tile = pyglet.image.load("path")
        self.render_phase = True
    def render(self):
        for i in range(len(self.island)):
            for j in range(len(self.island[i])):
                if self.island[i][j] == 0:
                    x = j*self.tile_width - i*self.tile_width + self.offsetx
                    y = int((j*self.tile_width+i*self.tile_width)/2+self.offsety)
                    pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.water_tile, x, y, batch=self.batch)
                elif self.island[i][j] == 1:
                    x = j * self.tile_width - i * self.tile_width + self.offsetx
                    y = int((j * self.tile_width + i * self.tile_width) / 2 + self.offsety)
                    pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.grass_tile, x, y, batch=self.batch)
    def draw(self):
        if self.render_phase:
            self.render()
            self.render_phase = False
        else:
            self.batch.draw()
```

Comment: first check if `else: self.batch.draw()` is executed. You could add some `print()` to this part of code.

Comment: it is executed, checked with print() call

Comment: In this example `draw` is executed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you don't assign `Sprites` to global or class variable(s) so it probably removes `Sprites` (as local objects) when it ends `render()`

```
def __init__(self):

    self.all_sprites = []

def render(self):

    s = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.water_tile, x, y, batch=self.batch)
    self.sprites.append(s)
```

---

Full example - try it with and without `self.sprites.append(s)`

```
import pyglet

class Island:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.image = pyglet.image.load("image.jpg")
        self.all_sprites = []
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        for y in range(0, 100, 30):
            for x in range(0, 100, 30):
                s = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.image, x, y, batch=self.my_batch)
                self.all_sprites.append(s)  # <-- try without this line

    def draw(self):
        print('island.draw()')
        self.my_batch.draw()

window = pyglet.window.Window()
island = Island()

@window.event()
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    island.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```